# javascript getelementbyid form encytype

Tags: javascript, upload, enctype

I am trying to write some markup to a div using javascript and it is not accepting the following markup

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">.
```

Is there something about that enctype that could be causing the problem or do I have a typo?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Jsfiddle

```
http://jsfiddle.net/smkqW/6/
```

Does not work with above text in; works if you take it out.

javascript

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="takePic('1');">Track Progress</a><div id = "puthere"></div>
```

html

```
function takePic(type){
    alert(type);
    var text = 'hello world<form action="upload.php" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">';
    var target = 'puthere';
   document.getElementById(target).innerHTML = text;
//return false;
```

Comment: Your fiddle has syntax errors

Comment: Yes.  It was a typo.  I updated it to work.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

javascript does not support multiline stings, you need to make sure your string is all on one line

```
 function takePic(type){
       alert(type);
       var text = 'hello world<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"></form>';
       var target = 'puthere';
       document.getElementById(target).innerHTML = text;
    //return false;     
 }
```

Comment: hackattack is right in that the problem is the string spreading across multiple lines. But JavaScript does support multiple line strings you just have to use the backslash character. You can see using this jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/smkqW/10/ the only change I made was adding a backslash to the first line of the string.